# fileupload is not working for php

Tags: php, html, file-upload

File upload value not commming for all values :
`print_r($_FILES);`

returns :

```
Array ( [file] => Array ( 
                          [name] => IMG_20150905_160429690.jpg 
                          [type] => [tmp_name] => [error] => 1 [size] => 0 ))
```

This is my HTML :

```
<form form action="profilepic_original_photo.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-horizontal" style="margin-top: 20px;">
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-xs-3">File Upload</label>
    <div class="col-md-9">
        <div class="fileupload fileupload-new" data-provides="fileupload">
            <div class="input-append">
                <div class="uneditable-input">
                    <!--<i class="fa fa-file fileupload-exists"></i>-->
                    <span class="fileupload-preview"></span>
                </div>
                    <span class="btn btn-default btn-file">
                        <span class="fileupload-exists">Change</span>
                        <span class="fileupload-new">Select file</span>
                        <input type="file" name="file" required>
                    </span>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-default fileupload-exists" data-dismiss="fileupload">Remove</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: Where is your file upload code????

Answer (score 1):

Well, `[error] => 1`, http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php says:

> Value: 1; The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini

Comment: which folder php.ini file is there i don't know??

Comment: you can find path to .ini file in your phpinfo(); just put file with `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` on your server & open it with browser. Also, add the `<form>` tag of your question, please.

Comment: In my php.ini just 4 line code are available see that code,,,,,,,   allow_url_fopen = On
safe_mode = Off
mysql.allow_persistent = Off
short_open_tag = On